# rails 5 run script only after server start

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5.1

I want to run a ftp listener class only when the server starts and not when console, generators, dbconsole, test, destroy, runner and rake commands run.

I've found some people doing same thing with rails 3 and 4 using checks like `defined? Rails::Generators` but I can't get it working in rails 5, I do not get any return with the defined check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `config.ru` file is only used by web servers and not loaded by the console script, rake tasks or even your test suite. What you put there is only executed when a server instance launches.

Web servers themselves have also ways to do this. When you use Puma for instance, there are hooks like `on_worker_boot` or `after_worker_boot`, which may come to help (http://www.rubydoc.info/github/puma/puma/Puma/Configuration/DSL).

However, I'd recommend integrating this into your deployed server environment and out of the Rails app.

Comment: Thank you for you reply @Christoph, would you explain why you think it'd be better to integrate in the server environment instead of in the rails server

Comment: Separation of concerns, I would say most of all. You already describe the problems you have when the Rails app does both. Depending on your deployment, the app server may run on like 5 workers. This means you have also 5 FTP listeners running. On the longer term you may want to scale your app, move the application server on a different server instance than the FTP listener.

Comment: This works for starting threads on a server while tests, rakes tasks, capistrano deploys and development do not start the threads.